# How can I make union in ZOd with custom Tpye?

Tags: typescript, zod

I want to have complex type union
I have in zod :

```
const LoginSchema=z.object({
  token:z.string(),
  user:UserSchema
})

const UserSchema=  z.object({
  _id: z.string().uuid(),
   online:z.boolean()
})
```

I want to have output sth like :

UserSchema | LoginSchema | LoginSchema[]

I think it would has to be enum but how ?
possible usage

```
 type r = z.enum([UserSchema , LoginSchema , LoginSchema[]] )
```

Comment: Have you tried `z.union`?

Comment: Yes, I received following error - 'z.union' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof z.union'?ts(2749)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a ZodUnion, not an enum:

```js
const r = z.union([UserSchema, LoginSchema, z.array(LoginSchema)])
```

All Zod types are values, not types. You'll need to infer the type after defining the zod schema.

```js
type R = z.infer<typeof r>
```